# Earn 10 reputation in order to answer this question

Tags: support, reputation

I saw a question, about a search engine, the very popular one that lets you acquire stuff. It turns out they don't let you exclude search terms, they don't have a negate search operator, and only support "natural" language inputs.

I phoned the vendor and got an answer from a real human, and now I want to share it. How do I earn 10 reputation in order to offer my answer? In fact just to upvote I need 15, so I'm confused about the priority of reducing spam and of way to add incentive for accurate answers? I've had an account for years. Does that not count? I'm also not a details person, so accuracy and truth for me are never going to be a thing, so unlikely to be able to pass your user exam which seems to be biased subconsciously against social fish like me by setting a test that involves tree climbing. I do appreciate it's a technical thing, but not everyone is that technical.

So how do I go about getting these 10 points?

Comment: [What is a “protected” or “highly active” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/21960)

Comment: For some reason, when I do post my question in Web applciations Meta (Which is not logical thing to do) it gets the identical response, based on experience when I asked a similar question a year ago and it just got moved there.

Yes I have been here for a long time, does not mean I visit often. Clearly not often enough to know what highly active/protected really entails if a question is old versus asking again creating a dupe/necro. My question got downvoted, which is not helping me to fix it in the slightest.

Comment: Related [Question protected by Community](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3860/88163), [Reputation how to get Stackexchange vote rights](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4699/88163)